# CSS - Grid row not recognized

Tags: html, css, grid, p5.js, square

I got a problem with my grid. Doing it for the first time, so sorry for that beginner question.

What I want to achieve is shown in this image (black borders):
[image: Image of my grid prototype]

Unfortunately, I already got stuck on my first line of code:

```css
body {

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 10% auto 10% 10% 10%;
  grid-template-rows: 60px auto; /*Isn't it recognizing my second row?*/
}

.temp {
  background-color: black;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Max S. Rodenkirchen - Sinn Sehen - FH AC 2022 - bei Eva Vitting</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

  </head>

  <body>


    <div class = "menu">

    </div>

    <div class = "temp">
      
    </div>

    <div class = "draw">
      
    </div>

    <div class = "label">
      
    </div>

    <div class = "slider">
      
    </div>

    <div class = "check">
      
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

The temp class should be on the left-hand side in the second row.

Another question I have is probably a bit more advanced.
The square area is going to be a P5 canvas that is always squared and should always stay in full grid row height.
I was wondering if I need to code something like this instead:

```
grid-template-columns: auto 60% auto auto auto;
```

But I am pretty sure I am missing something here.

Hope for some help :) This is going to be for a university project.
Max

Comment: I think you can use bootstrap to achieve this very easily. https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Comment: Ok nice. But shouldn't it be easy with CSS grids too? Unfortunately, I don't really have time to dig into sth new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems easier to take the top menu out of the grid as its dimensions don't seem to be directly related to the rest of the elements.

By contrast the big square looks as though it is 8 times the width of the narrower columns.

The big square can be made to take the same height as its width by giving it `aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;`

So we can define a one row grid with 4 columns at 1fr and the square at 8fr.

To make it easy for it to be centered this snippet puts it inside containers which have flex.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
}

.menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 1vw;
}

.container {
  width: 95%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 8fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 1vw;
}

.menu,
.container div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.temp {
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

.draw {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}

.label {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
}

.slider {
  grid-column: 4 / 5;
}

.check {
  grid-column: 5 / 6;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>Max S. Rodenkirchen - Sinn Sehen - FH AC 2022 - bei Eva Vitting</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>


  <div class="menu">

  </div>
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="temp">

      </div>

      <div class="draw">

      </div>

      <div class="label">

      </div>

      <div class="slider">

      </div>

      <div class="check">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This works perfectly fine. Thank you. 
What if I would want the menu left and right border to start at the same x.psoition as the .temp and .check areas?

Comment: In that case I'd include the menu in the grid and it would span all 12 columns grid-column: 1 / 13 and the others go to grid-row: 2 / 3

Comment: Ok cool. Thanks. 
Now I have the problem that I want my slider in .slider and my checkboxes in .check to be lined with each other. How would you do that?

Comment: Hi, I think this probably needs to be a separate question which includes code examples of the slider and checkboxes as we can’t tell from just the diagram,

Answer (score 0):

Your second row is there and the `.temp` div is place in that row. It's just that because the `.temp` div has no content and the second row has a height of `auto` that row and the `.temp` div inside it have zero height and so are not visible. You can see what is going on more easily by adding outlines and minimum height:

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 10% auto 10% 10% 10%;
  grid-template-rows: 60px auto;
}

div {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  min-height: 20px;
}

.temp {
  background-color: black;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
</div>

<div class="temp">
</div>

<div class="draw">
</div>

<div class="label">
</div>

<div class="slider">
</div>

<div class="check">
</div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks mate. Got this to work.